# Load image on UIWebView and scale it correctly

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I load an local image (tif) on to the `UIWebView`:

```
string fileName = "image.tif";
string localDocUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

The image is bigger than the `UIWebView`.

[image: Image width is wider than screen width]

Now I want that the image fits in the web view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

i am unable to give comment due to too less comment as i am a new user.

Plz goto nib file and check "Sceling" as "Scale page to fit"

Hope it will work

Comment: I'm creating the `UIWebView` programmatically. The `ScalesPageToFit` property is already set in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies directly to a picture, but I had issues trying to get a webview to show correctly on the screen. This is the code that I used and hopefully it can work for you.

```cs
var webview = new UIWebView(this.View.Frame);
webview.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(myCustomUrl)));
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(
        new UIViewController() { webview }, true);
```

Maybe setting the frame will help?

Comment: I'm setting the frame to the full size of the view with `webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);`. From your code I cannot see much difference to mine.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? This might better help identify what's going on.

Comment: I tried to upload the screenshot but it can happen that my provider has blocked this. So I cannot see if it works ...

Comment: What are the dimensions of the .tif?